# How to get the row and column name depending on condition pd.Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, find

Stuck with something that should be simple. I am trying to find a way to get the row and column name in where a certain condition is being fulfilled in `pd.Dataframe`. 
For example, give me the place where a certain value occurs:

```
  A  | B | C |D
1 'N' 'S' 'E' 'y'
2 'X' 'C' 'W' 'R'
```

Now I want to know where 'S' is - 1B (could be also, 1, B)

I've tried using just subsetting as `data[data =='x']`.index and such, but it just returns all indices. I've also tried to use `pd.where` and got the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a single occurrence:

```
res = df.where(df=='S').dropna(how='all').dropna(axis='columns',how='all')
[ f'{r}{c}' for r,c in zip(res.index, res.columns)]
```

Output:

```
['1B']
```

---

The following also works for multiple occurences:

```
import numpy as np
[f'{df.index[r]}{df.columns[c]}' for r,c in np.argwhere(df.to_numpy()=='S')]
```

Example:

```
   A  B  C  D
1  N  S  E  S
2  X  C  W  S
```

Output:

```
['1B', '1D', '2D']
```